# compare stored hash password with plaintext input user password

Tags: python, flask, hash, bcrypt

i have a stored hash password with bcrypt library so it always stores a different hash string in my db. How can i compare a string value with the store password if they are not the same?

```html
@login.route('/log',methods=['POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    # get data from JSON
    body = request.get_json()

    # if data contains something
    if body != error:
        # Verification of POST method
        if request.method == 'POST':
            # bucle for empty values findings
            validation = all(x != "" for x in body.values())
            if validation:
                username_mod = body['username']
                password_mod = body['password_hash']
                forced = b"valentina"
                hashed = hashpw(password_mod.encode('utf-8'), gensalt())
                userMatch = User.query.filter_by(username=username_mod).first()
                store_password = userMatch.password_hash
                
                if checkpw(forced, hashed):
                    print("it matches")
                else:
                    print("they dont")
                
                
                if userMatch:
                    if checkpw(hashed, store_password):
                        pswd_match = True
                    else:
                        pswd_match = False

                if userMatch and pswd_match:
                    return msg_handler("user allowed", 200)
                else:
                    return msg_handler("user denied", 400)
            else:
                return msg_handler("missing value in 1 or more parameters", 400)
        else:
            return msg_handler("Must be POST method", 400)
    else:
        return msg_handler("no data", 400)
```

im attaching my debug
[image]

Comment: encrypt the input password and compare it to the one in db, and try ```encrypt_pwd('pwd-goes-here') == 'encrypted-pwd-string-goes=here```

Comment: they are different cuz bcrypt library always changes value for hash. My password is already stored then i got a new string that i know is the same value as the stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve my problem using werkzeug.security
now my code is like this:

```
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

username_mod = body['username']
            password_mod = body['password_hash']
            userMatch = User.query.filter_by(username=username_mod).first()
            store_password = userMatch.password_hash

            if userMatch:
                if check_password_hash(store_password, password_mod ):
                    pswd_match = True
                else:
                    pswd_match = False

            if userMatch and pswd_match:
                return msg_handler("user allowed", 200)
            else:
                return msg_handler("user denied", 400)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're generating a new salt every time you hash the password. The salt is a randomly-generated value that gets attached to the password before it gets hashed.

If you and I both choose `abc123` as our passwords, then the hashes of our passwords will be the same too. If someone finds out my password is `abc123`, and they see that your hash is the same, then they'll know your password too. Now say that my password is `abc123` but when it gets hashed, it sticks a few random bytes at the beginning, say `7c6`. It then stores both my salt, `7c6`, and the hash of `7c6abc123`. You still use `abc123` as your password, but it randomly generates `9er` as the salt for you. It then stores `9er` as your salt, and the hash of `9erabc123`. Now our hashes look different, even though our passwords are the same.

Note that the salt is stored unencrypted. That's so you can enter your password, it can stick the salt on the front of it, then hash the salt + password combo. That hash is what needs to get compared to the stored hash. If you generate a new salt every time, the hash is going to be different every time.

So, this part:

```py
hashed = hashpw(password_mod.encode('utf-8'), gensalt())
```

should not generate a new salt. It needs to re-use the salt that was used (and stored) previously.

Comment: thanks for your help u gave the definition and behavior. i changed my code and i did use werkzeug.security

Comment: Glad it helped! Please mark the answer as accepted if you think it answers the question appropriately.